# Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I can't seem to figure this out.  I am trying to create dynamic tabs that will display a tab's content when clicked.  I am getting a "cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined" error in the console. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/babel">
  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        tabs: [
          {id: 0, name: 'Foo'},
          {id: 1, name: 'Bar'},
          {id: 2, name: 'Fizz'}
        ],
        contents: [
          {name: 'Foo', content: 'Hello'},
          {name: 'Bar', content: 'World'},
          {name: 'Fizz', content: 'Buzz'},
        ]
      };
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
      console.log('Hi');
    }
    renderTab(tab) {
      return(<Tab key={tab.id}
                  value={tab.name}
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
                  />
      );
    }
    renderContent(i) {
       return(<Content content={this.state.contents}/> );
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="container-tabs">
          <div className="tab">
            {this.state.tabs.map(this.renderTab)}
          </div>
          <div className="tabcontent">
            <p>{this.renderContent}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) ;
    }
  }

  class Tab extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <button className="tablinks"
                onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
          {this.props.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

  class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="tabcontent">
          {this.props.content}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue using the mentioned approaches?

Comment: Could you please mark it as the answer if it solves your problem above. That may be helpful someone reading this thread later. Make sure you do the same in future for the questions you posted in stack overflow as well. You can either up-vote, down-vote or mark it as the answer depending on how helpful it was to solve your initial problem. Anyway I am glad that you made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were lots of issues in your app. I fixed all of them and the new App component should be like this. Firstly inside the render method you need to call the two child components render methods using the `()`. Next to the `renderContent` function you need to pass one `content` instance at a time, not an array. I have posted the App component with all the changes I made to make it work below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tab from './tab';
import Content from './content';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          tabs: [
            {id: 0, name: 'Foo'},
            {id: 1, name: 'Bar'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Fizz'}
          ],
          contents: [
            {name: 'Foo', content: 'Hello'},
            {name: 'Bar', content: 'World'},
            {name: 'Fizz', content: 'Buzz'},
          ]
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick() {
        console.log('Hi');
      }

      renderTab(tab) {
        return(<Tab {...tab}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    />
        );
      }
      renderContent(content) {
        console.log(this.state.contents);
         return(<Content {...content}/> );
      }

      render() {
        return(
          <div className="container-tabs">
            <div className="tab">
              {this.state.tabs.map(tab => this.renderTab(tab))}
            </div>
            <div className="tabcontent">
              <p>{this.state.contents.map(content => this.renderContent(content))}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) ;
      }
}
```

Finally calling the `rendertab` function should be as follows. You haven't used map array helper properly.

```
{this.state.tabs.map(tab => this.renderTab(tab))}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to App's constructor `this.renderTab = this.renderTab.bind(this);`

You are losing App's `this` when doing the map in the render method, that's why it says it's not a function.